# Change in the Form of the Equation of Continuity with an increase in Turbulence

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, turbulence

Up until now, my learning has mostly been restricted to laminar (streamlined) flow, and its equations.
One such equation is the equation of continuity (A1V1=A2V2). I was wondering whether, with an increase in Reynold's number above turbulent or semi-turbulent levels, what from the equation would take.

Comment: What. are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

The equation of continuity
$$
\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+ \nabla\cdot (\rho {\bf v})=0
$$
is the same for all types of flows: laminar, turbulent, compressible, etc.